# Java 8 Function class addThen default method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am learning Java-8 Lambda, I am trying to understand addThen default method in java.util.function.Function interface.As per my understanding addthen will first execute the First function and then it will execute the second method.
   So I created a program like below:

```
//Pojo class 
  class Bike {

    public Bike(String bikeName, int price, String bikeType) {
        this.bikeName = bikeName;
        this.price = price;
        this.bikeType = bikeType;
    }

    private String bikeType;
    private String bikeName;
    private int price;

    public String getBikeType() {
        return bikeType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bike [bikeType=" + bikeType + ", bikeName=" + bikeName + ", price=" + price + "]";
    }

    public void setBikeType(String bikeType) {
        this.bikeType = bikeType;
    }

    public String getBikeName() {
        return bikeName;
    }

    public void setBikeName(String bikeName) {
        this.bikeName = bikeName;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}

//Main class
public class FunctionInbuildDefaultMethodsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        learningAndThen();
    }

    static void learningAndThen() {

        Function<Bike, String> updateBikefunction = (Bike bike) -> {
            System.out.println("OldBike Name is::" + bike.getBikeName());
            bike.setBikeName("PULSOR-200CC");
            return bike.getBikeName();
        };

        Function<Bike, String> updateBikePriceFunction = (Bike bike) ->  {

            System.out.println("OldBike Price is::" + bike.getPrice());
            bike.setPrice(95000);
            return bike.getBikeName();

        };

        /*
         * First update Bike and then price
         * */
         /*Compilation error here*/
        Function<Bike,String> bikeFunction = updateBikefunction.andThen(updateBikePriceFunction);
        bikeFunction.apply( new Bike("PULSOR-125CC", 65000, "BAJAJ"));

    }
 }
```

I am getting an compilation error at the line

```
 Function<Bike,String> bikeFunction =
updateBikefunction.andThen(updateBikePriceFunction);
```

as

> "The method andThen(Function) in the type Function is not applicable for the arguments (Function)"

, After looking into the source code of Function interface , I understand that 
   addThen default method is looking for instance of type `Function<String,Book>`. My questions is, If `addThen` default method is supposed to execute the first function and then the next fuction which is passed as parameter , why the `addThen` default method of function interface is written in such a manner excepting instance of type `Function<String,Book>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
updateBikefunction = Bike -> String
updateBikePriceFunction = Bike -> String

updateBikefunction -> updateBikePriceFunction = Bike -> String -> Bike -> String
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To form a chain of functions, the previous result should be an output for the next function. Here is this condition is broken.

The `updateBikefunction` could be changed to a `Function<Bike, Bike>`

```
    Function<Bike, Bike> updateBikefunction = (Bike bike) -> {
        ...
        return bike;
    };
```

to compile the line:

```
Function<Bike, String> bikeFunction = updateBikefunction.andThen(updateBikePriceFunction);
```

Answer (score 4):

`andThen` is applied to the *result* of that `Function`. So this would work for example:

```
Function<Bike, String> bikeFunction = updateBikefunction
                                       .andThen(s -> s.toUpperCase());
```

Since the result is a `String` from that `Function`.

Answer (score 3):

The `andThen` method of `Function` is used as a pipe between functions.

Both your `Function`s are take in a `Bike` and return a `String`, that's the problem.

When you invoke `[function1].andThen[function2]` where both have the same parametrization of `<Bike, String>`, `[function2]` is expecting a `Bike`, but receiving a `String` from `[function1]`.

See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) (my bold):

> Returns a composed function that first applies this function to its input, and then applies the after function **to the result**. If evaluation of either function throws an exception, it is relayed to the caller of the composed function.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

It's rather simple. A function does not output tuples like `(Bike, String)`, it has an input `Bike` and an output `String`.

If you now compose functions, then the second function needs to use that **output** as its **input** like:

```
Function1: A -> B
Function2: B -> C
Composed:  A (-> B) -> C
```

---

Your functions are both

```
updateBikefunction:      Bike -> String
updateBikePriceFunction: Bike -> String
```

however the compiler expects the `updateBikePriceFunction` to use the output of `updateBikefunction` as its input, so it wants it to look like:

```
updateBikePriceFunction: String -> ...
```

---

You can also clearly see this in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html):

> `Interface Function<T,R>`
>
> `andThen(Function<? super R,? extends V> after)`

So the object on which you invoke the method has input `T` and output `R`. The function you need to use as argument has input `? super R` and output `? extends V`.

---

### How to Fix

If you want to chain *manipulation methods* you should use `Bike -> Bike` and create an own method for such *final results* like `getBikeNameFunction` which then returns the name:

```
Function<Bike, Bike> updateBikefunction = (Bike bike) -> {
    System.out.println("OldBike Name is::" + bike.getBikeName());
    bike.setBikeName("PULSOR-200CC");
    return bike;
};

Function<Bike, Bike> updateBikePriceFunction = (Bike bike) ->  {
    System.out.println("OldBike Price is::" + bike.getPrice());
    bike.setPrice(95000);
    return bike;
};

Function<Bike, String> getBikeNameFunction = (Bike bike) -> {
    return bike.getBikeName();
};
```

You can now use it this way:

```
Function<Bike, String> bikeFunction = updateBikefunction
    .andThen(updateBikePriceFunction)
    .andThen(getBikeNameFunction);
```

Or alternatively just use the reference to the method like:

```
Function<Bike, String> bikeFunction = updateBikefunction
    .andThen(updateBikePriceFunction)
    .andThen(Bike::getName);
```